# c# regex first word matching

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string, named str, with a value of: `PRINT "HELLO WORLD"`

I'm trying to match it using Regex in C#, but this doesn't work:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^PRINT");
```

but if my str has a value of only `PRINT`, it matches.

What am I going to change in my regex expression in order to match the succeeding characters enclosed in quotation marks?

---

Edit:

I have this conditional block that is not touched when the str value is of `PRINT "Hello WOrld"`, but if it has `PRINT`, it does.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^PRINT")) {
    // some codes
}
```

---

Edit:

If the regex would to consider the keywork, `PRINT` and a block of string enclosed in quotation marks, separated by a space, what is the equivalent regex for that?
Is this correct?

```
@"^PRINT\w+\".*\""
```

How to delimit the quotation marks in the regex?

Comment: That line returns true.

Comment: You'll need to debug this. Either your string doesn't contain what you think it does, or you really are matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape `"` with `""` in verbatim string..To escape `"` in normal string you have to use `\"`

---

This would capture anything in between those two `"`

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^PRINT")) 
{
    Regex.Match(str,@"(?<="").*?(?="")").Value;//captures content within "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather you are trying to match the following list.  If you can be more explicit in what you are trying to match (more rules, etc) then making a regex for it should be fairly easy.

- starts with PRINT
- has 1+ non word character after
- has one quote
- has something (anything) after that
- has one quote
- end of line

You can try this:

```
var pattern = @"^PRINT[^\w]+""(.*)""$";  // you usually need those [] things :)

// * ""$ - requires the " to be at the end of the line
// * .* should match an empty quote ""
// you should trim the string on this one before matching
```

This is the test code that seems to show it working:

```
// notice that one of these has an embedded quote
var list = new [] { "PRINT", "PRINT ", "PRINT \"STUFF\"", "PRINT\t  \t\"AND \"FUN \"", " PRINT \"BAD\" " };
var pattern = @"^PRINT[^\w]+""(.*)""$";
foreach(var value in list) {
    var m = Regex.Match(value, pattern);
    if (m.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine("success: '{0}' found '{1}'", value, m.Groups[1].Value);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("failed:  '{0}'", value);
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
failed:  'PRINT'
failed:  'PRINT '
success: 'PRINT "STUFF"' found 'STUFF'
success: 'PRINT      "AND "FUN "' found 'AND "FUN '
failed:  ' PRINT "BAD" '
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string *str* contains any whitespace or invisible character just before `PRINT` then `Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^PRINT")` will return *false*, use `Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^.*PRINT")` instead.

***Example to extract `Hello WOrld` from input string:***

```
string strInput = @" PRINT ""Hello WOrld""";
string pattern = @"^.*PRINT\s*""(?<keyword>(\s*\S+\s*)+)""";

if (Regex.IsMatch(strInput, pattern)) {
    Match m = Regex.Match(strInput, pattern);
    string extractedValue = m.Groups["keyword"].Value;
}
```

In verbatim string, use double quotes `""` to escape single quote `"`

Comment: My str has been rid of whitespaces by using str.Trim(), so it's ok to use the @"^PRINT" I think..

Comment: But if it contains any invisible character then _@"^PRINT"_ will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\bPRINT\b");